# How to manually install veloeclipse plugin in eclipse luna (4.4.0)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to manually install "veloeclipse" plugin  in eclipse luna (4.4.0) other than install wizard available in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

In general if you would like to manually add a plugin to eclipse you can use the dropins folder.

- Step 1: Download the Plugin
- Step 2: Unzip the file, you should see
  two folders, `features` and `plugins`
- Step 3: Copy those folders
  directly into the /dropins folder (this folder is within your eclipse
  installation. e.g: `C:\DevApps\eclipse\dropins`
- Step 4: Restart Eclipse
  Step 5: Plugin will be installed, check `Help -> Installation Details
  -> Plugins`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

1. [Eclipse Directory Application](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html)
   Allows installation via script on commandline
2. [Eclipse Dropins Folder](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html) Just throw the plugins into a specific folder